# Kubernetes MySQL replication - Master service host inquiry

Tags: mysql, sql, docker, containers, kubernetes

I currently have a working MySQL master and slave with asynchronous replication set up on a Kubernetes cluster.

I'm trying to plan for a contingency if the master goes down, the slave will pick up the slack and what not. I figured the first step would be to review the Dockerfiles and scripts that define the `ENTRYPOINT` within the Dockerfiles.

When I `kubectl get svc`, this is the information I get about the services.
[image]

This tells me on the cluster, the master has an IP `10.0.156.209`.

Now when I flicked through the helper script `docker-entrypoint.sh` for the MySQL **slave** Docker image, I noticed this line which helps set up the master-slave scenario (I trimmed the line just to highlight this)

[image]

and when I boot into the **slave** pod on Kubernetes, the environment variable `$MYSQL_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST` is set to `10.0.156.209`

[image]

**My question:** How did the MySQL slave pod know to use the master's cluster IP as the value for `$MYSQL_MASTER_SERVICE_HOST`? Is this a Kubernetes thing or a SQL thing?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These environment variables are created automatically by Kubernetes for each Service. See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#environment-variables

> When a Pod is run on a Node, the kubelet adds a set of environment variables for each active Service.

On another note, mysql on Kubernetes is a complex topic. You probably don't want to roll your own solution. Have you looked at [Vitess](https://github.com/youtube/vitess)?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I must've missed that when I was doing some of the basic tutorials  Yeah it is a slight pain so far. I will look into Vitess :) Thank you for the suggestion!